# RTSP Client for H264 Audio/Video Stream

Tags: c#, camera, ffmpeg, emgucv

I'm looking for a simple way to get data of an IP Camera RTSP Stream (using H264 Audio/Video) and get on the other side

- a frame by frame byte[]
- a stream of the audio

After many research

- EmguCV Capture seems hanging forever (no answer from forum)
- There is many (too big) [RTSP Server](https://net7mma.codeplex.com/) few decode H264
- There is "slow" ffmpeg wrapper
- There is some managed DirectShow wrapper

So I don't know where to go ? And how to do this ?

It seems iSpyCamera is doing the job but it's a big project not a little library to query ip cameras.

Comment: Net7mma is my stack, it should work for this. Send a wireshark capture and I will check it out.

Comment: I have updated the code, the solution shouldn't bee "too big" anymore, it should also be more performant and use less memory than ffmpeg or libav.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look at Net7mma. I get some results with EmguCV 3.0.0 but my Ip Camera needs a buffer (1s in VLC)

Comment: Np, the library should support any size of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Emgu CV 3.0.0 works very well (see Emgu Sample)

I'm still stuck with my IP Camera working with VLC only if I add " :network-caching=1000" I don't know how to set that with Emgu CV

Answer (score 0):

If rtsp is hanging, u see to set up a rtsp server to keep the connection as the connection will be automatically turn off after receive both respond from the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Formerly I used this guide to achieve [RTSP streaming](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3001/how-to-implement-onvif-ip-camera-service-and-rtsp-streaming-to-smartph). This console application has been written in C# with the help of this [camera library](http://www.camera-sdk.com). Here's the corresponding code (connecting to the camera and streaming its image):

```
public class MyServer : IPCameraServer
    {
        private MediaConnector _connector;
        private IIPCamera _camera;
        private IIPCameraClient _client;

        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler ClientCountChange;

        public MyServer()
        {
            _connector = new MediaConnector();
            _camera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera("192.168.115.98:8080", "admin", "admin");

            if (_camera != null)
                _camera.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnClientConnected(IIPCameraClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
            _connector.Connect(_camera.AudioChannel, _client.AudioChannel);
            _connector.Connect(_camera.VideoChannel, _client.VideoChannel);

            var handler = ClientCountChange;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(null, new EventArgs());

            base.OnClientConnected(_client);
        }

        protected override void OnClientDisconnected(IIPCameraClient client)
        {
            _connector.Disconnect(_camera.AudioChannel, _client.AudioChannel);
            _connector.Disconnect(_camera.VideoChannel, _client.VideoChannel);
            _connector.Dispose();

            var handler = ClientCountChange;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(null, new EventArgs());

            base.OnClientDisconnected(client);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static MyServer _server = new MyServer();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _server.Start();
            _server.SetListenAddress("192.168.115.10", 554);
            _server.ClientCountChange += new EventHandler(server_ClientCountChange);
            Console.WriteLine("Started");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void server_ClientCountChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _server.ConnectedClients.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.TransportInfo.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ozeki component is paid, it seems to work but, the version you get for free has a very serious delay and the logo of the company :S